# Mostrar 'confirm' somente após o carregamento da pagina

Tags: javascript, html

Estou chamando a seguinte função dentro da pagina:

```
window.onload = function() {
    acess();
}

function acess() {

    decision = confirm("Deseja realmente excluir o servidor cadastrado abaixo?");

    if (decision) {
        window.location.replace("fin.del.cad.php");
    } else {
        history.back();
    }
}
```

Porem, o Confirm aparece e a pagina fica em branco carregando infinitamente até que eu clique no mesmo.

Gostaria que o Confirm e/ou alert após o carregamento da página e não antes.
Tentei algumas opções que vi em outros foruns e não deu muito certo.

Comment: Você pode deixar tb `window.onload = acess;` e inverter a ordem - deixar acess antes do onload.

Comment: Não funcionou :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode dar uma *atrasada* na caixa de confirmação colocando um `setTimeout` após o `.onload`. Um valor mínimo de 1 segundo pode ser suficiente (comentei os redirecionamentos para teste).

```js
window.onload = function() {
   setTimeout("acess()",1000);
}

function acess() {

    decision = confirm("Deseja realmente excluir o servidor cadastrado abaixo?");

    if (decision) {
        // window.location.replace("fin.del.cad.php");
    } else {
        // history.back();
    }
}
```

```html
Conteúdo da página
<br>
<img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" width="100">
```

#### Usando `readyState`

O `readyState` retornará *loading* até que a página esteja totalmente carregada. Após retornar *complete* eu ainda dou mais 1 segundo para executar a confirmação:

```
var chkReadyState = setInterval(function() {
    if (document.readyState == "complete") {
        clearInterval(chkReadyState);
        setTimeout("acess()", 1000);
    }
}, 100);
```

Comment: Cara, vc é muito topper, serviu direitinho, obrigado!

Comment: @Shinchila_Matadora Valeu! Cloquei na resposta uma outra opção. Abs!

Answer (score 1):

**O ATRIBUTO DEFER**

O atributo `defer` diz ao navegador para executar o script apenas quando a análise do HTML estiver finalizada.

```
<script defer src="script.js">
```

O script será requisitado assincronamente, seu download será completado e, apenas quando a análise do documento HTML estiver finalizada, ele será executado. Mesmo se o download completo do script acontecer antes da análise completa do HTML, ele só será executado depois.

Caso você venha a ter múltiplos elementos script com o atributo defer.

```
<script defer src="script.js">
<script defer src=“jquery.js">
<script defer src=“bootstrap.js">
```

Eles serão requisitados paralelamente e executados na sequência declarada.

**script.js**

```
decision = confirm("Deseja realmente excluir o servidor cadastrado abaixo?");

if (decision) {
    window.location.replace("fin.del.cad.php");
} else {
    history.back();
}
```

**O suporte para defer nos navegadores atuais é ótimo:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Créditos: [ASYNCHRONOUS VS DEFERRED JAVASCRIPT](https://bitsofco.de/async-vs-defer/)